# How to find if an id exist between two enumerable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am stuck at this issue. I have four models, Jobs, Users, Resumes, Applications

Associations are as follows

Each User has many jobs and many applications

Each Job belongs to a user

Each Resume belongs to a user

Each job has many applications

I need to restrict job poster to be able to view only resume of himself (since he can also be an applicant) and resumes of applicants who have applied on any job posted by him.

I can restrict the user to view his own resume by

```
if current_user.id == @resume.id
```

but cannot find a way to find all resume ids of users who have applied on all jobs posted by current user (as both are enumerable)

I only need to find if a resume id that logged in user wants to view is either his own or is among (exist?) in applications on all jobs posted by him

Need help...

Comment: Could you please clarify if table `jobs` has atleast 2 columns, one for `applicants` and another for `poster`? If not, how are you identifying who posted a job?

Comment: Can you include some of your model code rather than describe it with your word? (for the relation among objects

Comment: No Jobs only has one column user_id for the user who posted it. For appliant i use Jobapplications model which relate a job with the applicant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### User#has_one :resume

First, I think you have a typo, here :

```
if current_user.id == @resume.id
```

This can't work since current_user is an User and @resume is a Resume, so their id won't match.

You need to add `User#has_one :resume` and use :

```
if current_user.resume.id == @resume.id
```

### Job#has_many :resumes, through: :applications

Then, you need to use a [has_many through relation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

```
class Job
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :applications
  has_many :resumes, through: :applications
end
```

This allows you to do :

```
job.resumes
```

And that retrieves all resumes for the current job, filtering through applications for that job.

### Finding ids

Now, to have current user resume id and id for all resumes tied to job, you will go that way :

```
[ current_user.resume.id ] + current_user.jobs.includes( :resumes ).references( :resumes ).map { |job| job.resumes.map( &:id ) }.flatten
```

`current_user.jobs.includes( :resumes ).references( :resumes )` load user's jobs, and preload resumes in the query.

`.map { |job| job.resumes.map( &:id ) }` retrieves resume ids.

`.flatten` reduce array to a single dimension, since you would have an array of ids for each job, else.

Finally, we concat this array with an array containing resume id for current user.

### Checking current resume id

Now that you have all of that, you just need to check if current resume id is included in that array :

```
relative_resumes = [ current_user.resume.id ] + current_user.jobs.includes( :resumes ).references( :resumes ).map { |job| job.resumes.map( &:id ) }.flatten
if relative_resumes.include? @resume.id
  # profit !
end
```